# Can not connect docker hosted SSMS from containerized GraphQL api

Tags: node.js, sql-server, docker, express, typeorm

I am using SQL Server image as DB and trying to connect it with GraphQL api written using TypeORM. If I run `docker-compose up -d` it is simply runs the DB(I can connect it from local SSMS) but API is not able to connect it.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
# Copy app source code
COPY . .
#Expose port and start application
EXPOSE 4000
CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

Docker-Compose File:

```
version: "2"
services: 
  server: 
    build: .
    ports: 
    - "4000:4000"
    depends_on: 
    - plhdashboardb
  plhdashboardb:
    container_name: plhdashboardb
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    ports: 
      - "1434:1433"
    environment: 
      SA_PASSWORD: "I_AM_mr_React"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

Building it using `docker build -t server .` and running it using `docker-compose up -d`

If I try to run the URL `http://localhost:4000/graphql`, it never loads, but Server can be connected from local SSMS.

ormconfig.json:

```
{
   "type": "mssql",
   "host": "plhdashboardb",
   "username": "sa",
   "password": "I_AM_mr_React",
   "database": "plhdashboardb_Dev_Mock",
   "synchronize": true,
   "autoSchemaSync": true,
   "logging": false,
   "options": {
      "encrypt": true,
      "enableArithAbort": true
   },
   "entities": [
      "src/entity/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "migrations": [
      "src/migration/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "subscribers": [
      "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
      "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
      "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
   },
   "seeds": [
      "src/database/seeds/**/*{.ts,.js}"
   ],
  "factories": [
     "src/database/factories/**/*{.ts,.js}"
   ]
}
```

If I enter the container `docker exec -it server_server_1 bash` and run `npm run dev` and getting this error:

```
(node:167) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1434 - Could not connect (sequence)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious/connection-pool.js:68:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
    at Connection.socketError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1290:12)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1116:21
    at SequentialConnectionStrategy.connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/connector.js:87:14)
    at Socket.onError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/connector.js:100:12)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:167) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:167) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

Comment: The host and port in the error message suggests the connection string is incorrect. "localhost:1434" is used on the container host (e.g. from SSMS) but in the container network, it should be "plhdashboardb,1433" if configured properly.

Comment: Just a dumb question, @DanGuzman are you suggesting me to change `container_name: plhdashboardb` to `container_name: plhdashboardb,1433` ?

Comment: No, the container name and sql port are different settings. I don't know where typeorm is picking up the name localhost or port 1434 since it's not in the ormconfig.json in your question.

Comment: exactly, I thing its a default configuration. Well, not sure although.

Comment: I am facing the same problem but there is no way to solve it